# CSS Animation not clearing in JS

Tags: javascript, css

I'm penning a digital clock and I want to create a feature that slides the numbers up on change. I'm applying inline animation to the `secondDiv` and clearing it every second, but the animation only shows up on page load. I want it to show every second, hence trying to clear it first. I've tried `secondDiv.style.animation = ""` as well as `secondDiv.removeAttribute('style')`, but to no avail.

[Codepen Example](https://codepen.io/Sackadelic/pen/qBNwYwL)

### JS

```
const clock = document.querySelector("#clock-body");
const hourDiv = document.querySelector("#hours");
const minuteDiv = document.querySelector("#minutes");
const secondDiv = document.querySelector("#seconds");
const zone = document.querySelector("#zone");

const getDate = () => {
  let date = new Date();
  let hours = date.getHours();
  let minutes = date.getMinutes();
  let seconds = date.getSeconds();

  if (hours > 12) {
    hours = hours - 12;
  }
  if (minutes < 10) {
    minutes = `0${minutes}`;
  }

  if (seconds < 10) {
    seconds = `0${seconds}`;
  }
  hourDiv.textContent = hours;
  minuteDiv.textContent = minutes;
  secondDiv.textContent = seconds;

  secondDiv.style.animation = `0.3s change`;
};

window.setInterval(getDate, 1000);
```

### CSS

```
@keyframes change {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(-30px);
  }
}
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I clear the Inline Animation every second before it's applied again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove style just after animation is finished with help of [`animationend`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/animationend_event) event. Without waiting for next loop.

Instead of:
`secondDiv.removeAttribute("style");`

Use

```
secondDiv.addEventListener('animationend', () => {
    secondDiv.removeAttribute("style");
});
```

outside your `getDate` function

Full example

```js
const clock = document.querySelector("#clock-body");
const hourDiv = document.querySelector("#hours");
const minuteDiv = document.querySelector("#minutes");
const secondDiv = document.querySelector("#seconds");
const zone = document.querySelector("#zone");

const getDate = () => {
    
    
    let date = new Date();
    let hours = date.getHours();
    let minutes = date.getMinutes();
    let seconds = date.getSeconds();

    if (hours > 12) {
        hours = hours - 12;
    }
    if (minutes < 10) {
        minutes = `0${minutes}`;
    }

    if (seconds < 10) {
        seconds = `0${seconds}`;
    }
    hourDiv.textContent = hours;
    minuteDiv.textContent = minutes;
    secondDiv.textContent = seconds;
    
    secondDiv.style.animation = `0.3s change`;

    
};

secondDiv.addEventListener('animationend', () => {
    secondDiv.removeAttribute("style");
});

window.setInterval(getDate, 1000);
```

```css
body {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    background: linear-gradient(#444, #222);
    height: 100vh;
    color: #fff;
}

#clock-body {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    font-size: 2rem;
    font-family: "Courier New", Courier, monospace;
    padding: 2.5rem;
    border: 10px solid #fff;
    border-radius: 20px;
    background: #000;
    box-shadow: 0 8px 30px #212121;

    span {
        font-weight: 300;
        font-size: 3rem;
    }

    #hours,
    #minutes,
    #seconds {
        font-weight: 700;
        font-size: 4rem;
        border-radius: 3px;
    }
}

@keyframes change {
    0% {
        transform: translateY(0);
    }
    100% {
        transform: translateY(-30px);
    }
}
```

```html
<div id="clock-body">
    <div id="hours"></div>
    <span>:</span>
    <div id="minutes"></div>
    <span>:</span>
    <div id="seconds"></div>
    <div id="zone"></div>

</div>
```

Comment: Ah. Never knew about the `animationend` event. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution, Its not perfect, but it can be a good starting point.

I am using `setTimeout` inside the function along with `transition` property of css to control the position and opacity of the number

```js
const clock = document.querySelector("#clock-body");
const hourDiv = document.querySelector("#hours");
const minuteDiv = document.querySelector("#minutes");
const secondDiv = document.querySelector("#seconds");
const zone = document.querySelector("#zone");

const getDate = () => {
  // secondDiv.removeAttribute("style");
  secondDiv.style.transition = `opacity 0.3s linear`;
  secondDiv.style.transform = `translateY(0px)`;
  secondDiv.style.opacity = `1`;
  let date = new Date();
  let hours = date.getHours();
  let minutes = date.getMinutes();
  let seconds = date.getSeconds();

  if (hours > 12) {
    hours = hours - 12;
  }
  if (minutes < 10) {
    minutes = `0${minutes}`;
  }

  if (seconds < 10) {
    seconds = `0${seconds}`;
  }
  hourDiv.textContent = hours;
  minuteDiv.textContent = minutes;
  secondDiv.textContent = seconds;

  setTimeout(() => {
    secondDiv.style.transition = `all 0.3s linear`;
    secondDiv.style.transform = `translateY(-50px)`;
    secondDiv.style.opacity = `0`;
  }, 500);
};

window.setInterval(getDate, 1000);
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: linear-gradient(#444, #222);
  height: 100vh;
  color: #fff;
}

#clock-body {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 2rem;
  font-family: "Courier New", Courier, monospace;
  padding: 2.5rem;
  border: 10px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 20px;
  background: #000;
  box-shadow: 0 8px 30px #212121;
}

#clock-body span {
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 3rem;
}

#clock-body #hours,
#clock-body #minutes,
#clock-body #seconds {
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 4rem;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

@keyframes change {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(-30px);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="clock-body">
  <div id="hours"></div>
  <span>:</span>
  <div id="minutes"></div>
  <span>:</span>
  <div class="s-div" id="seconds"></div>
  <div id="zone"></div>

</div>
```